# How do I load columns of a second table as properties on a model in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I am trying to load columns from a second table in the database as properties on a model using NHibernate. I'm using an XML mapping file and tried using the *join* tag. When I build and try to run the code, I get the following error:

> The element 'join' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has
>   invalid child element 'key' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'.
>   List of possible elements expected: 'property, many-to-one, component,
>   dynamic-component, any, map, set, list, bag, idbag, array,
>   primitive-array, sql-insert, sql-update, sql-delete' in namespace
>   'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'.

The following is a snippet of the mapping file:

```
<class name="Article" table="article">
    <id name="Id" column="articleID" unsaved-value="-1" type="Int32">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="ClientId" column="accountID" type="Int32" />
    <property name="PublicNumber" column="articleNum" />    
    <join table="articleLanguage">
        <key column="accountID" />
        <key column="articleNum" />
        <property name="Question" />
        <property name="LanguageId"/>
    </join>
</class>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This aproach, would be working only if the root entity (Article) would have composite key:

```
<class name="Article" table="article">
    // not and <id> mapping
    <!--<id name="Id" column="articleID" unsaved-value="-1" type="Int32">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>-->
    // but <composite-id>
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="Id" column="articleID" ></key-property>
      <key-property name="PublicNumber" column="articleNum"></key-property>
    </composite-id>

    <property name="ClientId" column="accountID" type="Int32" />
    <!-- <property name="PublicNumber" column="articleNum" /> -->
    <join table="articleLanguage"> 
        <!-- key is represented as ONE key with two columns
        <!--
          <key column="accountID" />
          <key column="articleNum" />
        -->
        <key >
          <column name="accountID"></column>
          <column name="articleNum"></column>
        </key>
        <property name="Question" />
        <property name="LanguageId"/>
    </join>
</class>
```

I can understand that this is not what you prefer. But, if there are two columns representing relation, there is simply no other way. Because to be able to find exactly one row to join... we need both keys.

Comment: I realized as I beat my head against this problem that NHibernate was yelling at me that there were too many <key> tags under <join>. It seems it was expecting only one? I'm guessing that's to line up with the number of IDs (one) defined earlier in the class. If that's the case, I imagine your change would fix it.

Comment: The bad is, that you have to introduce composite-id. It is good solution here.. but in a longer run, you will hate your article entity, because its handling will become nigthmare... Try to re-think that. I would go with a `<bag>` mapping (many joined items with different `articleNum`) - because then you can have clear entity objects (article just with an `articleID` as column). Later you can filter the collection.. to find the one item, which also has same number as the root article.. hope it helps a bit...

Comment: You've been helpful. For the time being I've gone with <joined-subclass> to have inheritance. I think that actually solves my problem the best. I'm going to talk to the DBAs tomorrow about changing the keys so it's not a composite key. Everything I read online says composite keys are a pain with NHibernate.

Comment: Exactly.. try to avoid composite keys.. My experience says: 1) standard surrogate key 2) relations just one-to-many or many-to-one ... the rest is great stuff, but pain later if our application is successful...